# How to import a flat text file into an array without using pandas?

Tags: python

I have a textfile database with information about different people, and I need to conduct some analysis on this using Python. The file contents are formatted as shown below:

```
First name: Jeff  
Last name: Frost  
ID number: 190293  
Height: 194  
Children: George, Mary

First name: Helen  
Last name: Oliver  
ID number: 198895  
Height: 164
```

and so on for around another 1000 people. I would like to make this into a data structure that I can use for further analysis, but I am not too sure how to as the format is very different from what I practiced with before.

Another problem I have is that for the people without children, that line is completely missing (as with Helen in the example). To make things more difficult, I can only use the standard library and numpy (not pandas which is what I would have tried to use otherwise).

Comment: Why are your children linked by names not ID? Also, have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can't use any particularly useful third party library (why not, anyway?) then you'll have to do it "by hand".

You'll be opening the text file and reading it in line by line, and then checking the content of the line: If it's not empty, you can then use the `split` method of string objects to get to the fields, and maybe a further `split` to get the individual children if there's a children line. If the line is empty, you'll start a new record.

So that's high-level how you'd do it, and I encourage you at this point to give it a try and then come back if you have further specific questions. But figuring out on your own how to read a file line by line and split a string etc is valuable experience :)

Answer (score 0):

I will avoid one-liners so it is easier to understand. I'm assuming you know how to open your text document, I just copy-pasted it in the snippet below:

```
string = '''First name: Jeff
Last name: Frost
ID number: 190293
Height: 194
Children: George, Mary

First name: Helen
Last name: Oliver
ID number: 198895
Height: 164'''

people = [ prop for prop in string.split('\n\n') ] # Separating Jeff from Helen
properties = [i.split('\n') for i in people] # Separating their properties.
l = []
for p in properties:
    l.append(dict([i.split(':') for i in p])) # Turn each persons' properties into dictionaries
```

`l` will be a list of dictionaries, similar to a `json` file. If you would turn this into a DataFrame, this would give:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Output:

```
      First name Last name ID number Height       Children
0       Jeff     Frost    190293    194   George, Mary
1      Helen    Oliver    198895    164            NaN
```